# Semi-Sticky footer behind content

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to create a sticky footer from an image of 360px height, but I like that 160px of image to be behind the content and 200px to remain sticky.
My css is:

```
html {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0 0 360px;
 background: #049ec4
}

#wrap {
 width: 90%;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #809FFF
}

footer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 360px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #049ec4 url("http://phonegap.com/css/images/cloud.jpg") 0 50% repeat-x;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RC3Za

but is creating a unwanted space, I like css to output like this:
[image: made with ms paint]

Comment: look at this image http://phonegap.com/css/images/cloud.jpg .. here css code is not a problem mate.. you have a problem with your image. just cut the top size of this image and try again...

Comment: yes i know, image is bigger, in that space I like to draw few airplanes in future, but for now is possible with css so wrap div to go a little above the clouds like in the image I've uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **footer position to relative** and instead of using the bottom property, set the **top property to -250px** or whatever you want. Set the **z-index property to -1** to get it behind the wrap.

Take a look here: http://jsbin.com/picazedu/1/edit

**EDIT:**
A better solution, to avoid the footer being displayed in the middle of the window, is applying the background image to the body and adjusting it with the `background-position:bottom left` property. Now you can give the `footer` the height you want to fit the background image where you want: http://jsfiddle.net/YQMyc/4/

Comment: hmm yes but in this case footer is in middle of screen